# "Update" method on google sheets API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I'm facing "Update" method on google sheets API error. What's happening is when I am trying too add values in my spreadsheet on a cell, well the first value go normally but when I am trying to add another value in that same range it just overwrites in the previous cell and does not goes to the new row. Note I am using Node.js. I am making a application which is a discord bot. I am trying to add values from the bot that's why you can see arguments in my code.

```
async function gsrun3(cl, connection) {

  const sheets = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth: cl
  });
  let values = [
    [
      args[0]
    ],
  ];
  let resource = {
    values
  };
  const opt3 = {
    spreadsheetId: '1Nqddy8X63Ao7JIgjIqkf-bADSU_7TAeFPAQROxgs1uw',
    range: args[1] + "!G2:G",
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    resource,
  }
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(opt3, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log("Values added")
    }
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to append the values to new row of the column "G" when the script is run using Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose to use the method of "spreadsheets.values.append" in Sheets API instead of the method of "spreadsheets.values.update".

  - By this, the values are appended to the new row when the script is run.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(opt3, (err, result) => {
```

To:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(opt3, (err, result) => {
```

- When this modified script is run, the values are appended to the column "G".

Your whole script is as follows.

```js
const sheets = google.sheets({
  version: "v4",
  auth: cl,
});
let values = [[args[0]]];
let resource = {
  values,
};
const opt3 = {
  spreadsheetId: "1Nqddy8X63Ao7JIgjIqkf-bADSU_7TAeFPAQROxgs1uw",
  range: args[1] + "!G2:G",
  valueInputOption: "RAW",
  resource,
};
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(opt3, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Values added");
  }
});
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: Ok sir Thanks for answering my question I tried to use append yesterday but there is slight problem I faced that is as you know append only adds a new row after last of every sheet I mean like Collumn A there are values like Apples Mangoes and after this there is one cell gap then I have my bananas now what append will do is it will skip that gap in the middle and add the new value after bananas. But I don't want this to happen I want my system to fill that gap first then add after the last value.

Comment: @Tech And Gaming Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can you explain about your current situation using an image? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I do not know how can I post images here

Comment: @Tech And Gaming Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? By this, I would like to confirm your situation.